# passing data to componnet onClick in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

We have 2 components. one is Test1 and the second one is Test2.
My question is how we can pass data from component Test1 to Test2(they are separated components.) onClick event. :
for e.g a function like this:

```
  const ClickHandler =()=>{
        //pass data to Test2
      
  }
```

Comment: Data is generally passed via props to children components, but there are other methods for storing data and passing it around. You've not provided enough context to really provide a useful answer. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there will be two methods to do this.

1. Be a child of the same parent and share props.

```js
  import {useState} from "React"
   
  const TestOneComponent = ({value}) => (
    <span>{value.toString()}<span>
  )

  const TestTwoComponent = ({value, onClick}) => (
    <span>{value.toString()}</span>
    <button onClick={onClick}>Increase Value</button>
  )

  const ParentComponent = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(0)

    const onClick = () => {
      setValue(value + 1)
    }

    return (
      <>
        <TestOneComponent value={value}>
        <TestTwoComponent value={value} onClick={onClick}>
      </>
    )
  }
```

2. Manage store and pass props to those two components.

Comment: can you explain method 2, please?

Comment: It is the same as the first method in concept. Share props. But just use global store.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use props to pass data in to the other component and render it when the onClick event is triggered or

you can navigate to a new page by onClick event and pass data into the header/route and access that data in the new page's component